# What is the significance of the location of the files of an installed program on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, system-administration

Once a program is installed in Linux, sometimes I find out that it is easier to put in a different location. In general, what is the significance of the location of the files of an installed program on Linux?

Often the advice on the internet is to add the (wrong or inconvenient) paths to environment variables. I'd much rather move the files to locations where they are automatically found by commands and programs.

One recent example is site-packages of Python. My Python did not appear to check the PYTHONPATH variable, moving the libraries there to the Python2.7/ directory worked well.
Now Ia m facing the same issue with OpenCV.

I also wonder why Linux installation does not prompt (like Windows) for the desired installation directory and why, so often, things wind up in places where they don't work?

Comment: The location is significant in order for program to find their files. A program, looking for a file it needs in a location where that file isn't, results in the program not able to access it. Therefore the file is better there where program expects it. Significant, therefore.  "so often, things wind up in places where they don't work?" - not my experience. change your distribution to something saner. "wonder why Linux installation does not prompt (like Windows) for the desired installation directory" - shouldn't question be "why windows prompts ..."  instead?

Answer (score 2):

In general, programs are installed in /usr/bin (for binaries) and /usr/lib, or a specific path to that specific linux distro, so that any program that you install that uses a specific library/program will search in that path for it. If you install a program in a different path, let's say /home/user/program, it will be installed locally and other programs won't be able by default to access it.

You can install any program wherever you want. However, it is good use to use the repo and install them in the general path.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you install programs, but I use apt-get and dpkg on Ubuntu. You can also install some python modules this way.

Generally you are supposed to use the package system provided by your distro (IMHO).
If you do not use packages then you are on your own.

About PYTHONPATH. Did you add it to your .bashrc and made sure that it was set in the terminal you are using?

Also please see: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard